# How to convert char(or string, other type) -> bits?

Tags: c++

In c++,
I don't understand about this experience. I need your help.
in this topic, answers saying use to_string.
but they say 'to_string' is converting bitset to string and cpp reference do too.
So, I wonder the way converting something data(char or string (maybe ASCII, can convert unicode?).
{It means the statement can be divided bit and can be processed it}

The question "How to convert char to bits?"
then answers say "use to_string in bitset"
and I want to get each bit of my input.
Can I cleave and analyze bits of many types and process them? If I can this, how to?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char letter;
    cout << "letter: " << endl;
    cin >> letter;
    cout << bitset<8>(letter).to_string() << endl;
    bitset<8> letterbit(letter);
    int lettertest[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        lettertest[i] = letterbit.test(i);
    }
    cout << "letter bit: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        cout << lettertest[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    int test = letterbit.test(0);

}
```

When executing this code, I get result I want.
But I don't understand 'to_string'.
An important point is using of "to_string"
{to_string is function converting bitset to string(including in name),
then Is there function converting string to bitset???
Actually, in my code, use the function with a letter -> convert string to bitset(at fitst, it is result I want)}

help me understand this action.

Comment: Can you try rephrasing your question? I'm having difficulties understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: What is a bitset?

> https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/
>
> A bitset stores bits (elements with only two possible values: 0 or 1,
> true or false, ...).
>
> The class emulates an array of bool elements, but optimized for space
> allocation: generally, each element occupies only one bit (which, on
> most systems, is eight times less than the smallest elemental type:
> char).

In other words, a "bitset" is a *binary* object (like an "int", a "char", a "double", etc.).

Q: What is bitset<>.to_string()?

> Bitsets have the feature of being able to be constructed from and
> converted to both integer values and binary strings (see its
> constructor and members to_ulong and to_string). They can also be
> directly inserted and extracted from streams in binary format (see
> applicable operators).

In other words, to_string() allows you to convert the binary bitset to text.

Q: How to to I convert convert char(or string, other type) -> bits?

A: Per the above, simply use bitset<>.to_ulong()

Here is an example:

> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <bitset>
> int main()
> {
>     std::bitset<8> b(42);
>     std::cout << b.to_string() << '\n'
>               << b.to_string('*') << '\n'
>               << b.to_string('O', 'X') << '\n';
> }
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 00101010
> **1*1*1*
> OOXOXOXO
> ```

Comment: I want to ask wonder if my understanding is right. 'b.to string'  changes the bitset of 42(init value) to 'String' with parameters?.(Not translate binary to string!?) and default strings (without parameter like 'O', 'X', etc..) are 1, 0?